# VBA script using contains not working

Tags: vba, excel, contains

Trying to do a simple VBA script to look at a field and if that field contains 99 in the middle then show another field. I can get a normal statement to work i.e. `field2 = "5D992"` but not a contains statement using wild cards (see script below).  I think it might be just my syntax is wrong, any ideas anyone??

```
Sub OnFormat

    IF rpt.field3.Text.contains "*99*" THEN 
        rpt.field2.visible = false
    Else 
        rpt.field2.Visible = true
    End If

End Sub
```

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using `InStr`.

```
If InStr(1, rpt.field3.Text, "99", vbTextCompare) Then 
   rpt.field2.visible = false 
Else 
    rpt.field2.visible = true 
End If
```

See [MSDN InStr Function documentation for more information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8460tsh1(v=vs.90).aspx)

Comment: Thanks for this Smittey, but are wildcards not used for this function??

Comment: You're welcome! If I understand the question correctly, do you mean using a wildcard character (e.g. '*')? If so, this InStr function will look for 99 in the string supplied to the second argument (`rpt.field3.Text`) so effectively it is using wildcards, so `"*99*"`!

Comment: Great thanks for the explanation, much appreciated.  The script works wonderful now, much appreciated.